# How to define dependent function in a single js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I have a nodejs project in which a sample.js include two function 
function A depends on function B's callback .

```
// smaple.js

    //Both function are included in the same file 

        function B ( arg1 , callback ){
            // do some async
            async.map(arg1 , function(item, cb){
                     var a = item.a
                     var b = a*4
                     cb( null , {'a':a,'b':b})  
                },function(err , result){
                callback(err , result)
            } )


        }


        function A ( arg , callback ){
            if(condition1){
            callback(null , 1)
            }else{
             B ( arg , function( err , result){
                if(err){
                 callback(err , result)
                }
                else if (result ==1 ){

                callback ( null , 2)
                }else{
                callback ( null , 1)
                }

             })
            }
        }
```

Scenario 2

```
        // function B is in outer.js and included as module
         //sample.js

        var outerfunction = require('./outer.js');

        function A ( arg , callback ){
            if(condition1){
            callback(null , 1)
            }else{
             outerfunction.B ( arg , function( err , result){
                if(err){
                 callback(err , result)
                }
                else if (result ==1 ){

                callback ( null , 2)
                }else{
                callback ( null , 1)
                }

             })
            }
        }


        outer.js


        function B ( arg1 , callback ){
            // do some async
            async.map(arg1 , function(item, cb){
                     var a = item.a
                     var b = a*4
                     cb( null , {'a':a,'b':b})  
                },function(err , result){
                callback(err , result)
            } )


        }

        module.exports.B = B ;
```

Does scenario 1 is a proper way to use function ?
What will happen if this code run concurrently using cluster module?

Does scenario 2 is better way to use dependent function ?
Is this code perform better on concurrent execution?

Which scenario is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, the javascript file is first parsed before it is run and at parse time all functions defined like A and B become known.  So, all top level functions are defined before any code has run.  Some people refer to this as hoisting as all function definitions within a scope are hoisted to the top of the scope and available in the whole scope.

As such, you could do this:

```
B();

function A() {
}

function B() {
}
```

And, everything would be just fine.

This "hoisting" is true ONLY for functions defined with the function declaration syntax shown above.  it is not true for function assignments such as:

```
var B = function() {
};
```

In that case, `var B` is hoisted to the top of the scope, but it is not assigned the function value until that line of code actually executes and it will execute in the sequential order of the code.  So, this would not work:

```
B();

var A = function() {
}

var B = function() {
}
```

as `B` will not yet be assigned a its function value when you try to execute it.

---

Applying this info to your two scenarios, your first scenario shoudl work just fine because both A and B are hoisted function definitions and available anywhere in the file.

Your second scenario would also work fine because you have explicitly loaded the module and obtained a reference to `B` before it is called.

There should be no difference in the two when using a cluster module.  The files will be loaded once at startup and will already be loaded before you ever get multiple requests going in a cluster module.

Comment: if the function A is called from function C and function D at a same time then there will be two instance of function A will be created inside the v8 heap in both scenario ?

Comment: @Vicb - There won't be two instances of the function created within a single instance of node.js.  There's only one function definition shared by the interpreter.  There will be two runtime structures created that represent the state of execution of a function, but that is absolutely required as each one has it's own local variables and local state.  Now, if you're firing up multiple instances of node, then of course, all the code is loaded separately into each instance of node.js.

Comment: Thanks just one more quick question if C and D accessing two different runtime of A then if any runtime of A fails or creates an error it wont effect the another runtime of A ?.

Comment: @Vicb - Suppose you have two instances of node running as a cluster.  The code in instance 1 will only ever call other functions in instance 1 and code in instance 2 will only ever call other functions in instance 2.  An incoming web request is directed to one node instance in the cluster and after it's directed to a specific instance that request runs only on that instance until the request is finished.  You can think of it logically like you have a load balancer in front of multiple servers all running copies of the same code.